# Convert to from scientific notation to decimal with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scientific-notation

I am trying to plot some test data (show at the end of this post), using `ggplot` using the following command:

```
options(scipen=20)    
ggplot(testData,aes(x=Group.1, y=x), format(scientific=FALSE)) + 
scale_x_discrete(name="Test", formatter=comma) + geom_bar()
```

The plot generates well enough, but the x-axis is in scientific notation (as in the test data), how would i go about displaying it at decimal instead?
(As shown in the command i already tried the scipen option and various formatter options - as suggested in other posts on this site)

**My test data:**

```
> str(testData)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
$ Group.1: Factor w/ 5 levels "(1.3e+03,1.5e+03]",..: 1 2 3 4 5
$ x      : num  80000 94000 86000 112000 98000

> testData
            Group.1      x
1 (1.3e+03,1.5e+03]  80000
2 (1.5e+03,1.7e+03]  94000
3 (1.7e+03,1.9e+03]  86000
4 (1.9e+03,2.1e+03] 112000
5 (2.1e+03,2.3e+03]  98000

> dput(testData)
structure(list(Group.1 = structure(1:5, .Label = c("(1.3e+03,1.5e+03]", 
"(1.5e+03,1.7e+03]", "(1.7e+03,1.9e+03]", "(1.9e+03,2.1e+03]", 
"(2.1e+03,2.3e+03]"), class = "factor"), x = c(80000, 94000, 
86000, 112000, 98000)), .Names = c("Group.1", "x"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

*The generation of testData:*

```
testData <- aggregate(as.numeric(as.character(housing7$PRICE)),
                      by=list(cut(as.numeric(as.character(housing7$SIZE)), 
                      breaks=5)), FUN=mean)
```

Comment: Post your `testData` with `dput(testData)`.

Comment: Hereby done, didn't know that command - thanks!

Comment: Also, how did you create that factor (`testData$Group.1`)? Did you use `cut` or something?

Comment: Yep, cut() and aggregate() - just added to the post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once the labels of your factor are stored in scientific notation, it isn't easy to go back to normal notation.

Since you used `cut` to create this factor, you can change the number of digits used in the label with the `dig.lab` argument. For example:

```
testData <- aggregate(as.numeric(as.character(housing7$PRICE)),
by=list(cut(as.numeric(as.character(housing7$SIZE)), breaks=5,dig.lab=6)), FUN=mean)
```

Comment: Aha! dig was excatly what i was looking for! Thanks! BTW, any way to make my cuts clean? (as in cut in whole numbers)

Comment: Note that there was a bracket error in that code, check the updated version.

Comment: Check out `?cut`. It gives a bunch of options. Try specifying the breaks you want instead of just `breaks=5` like `breaks=c(100,200)`.